# why does creating a fork in the middle of my program change my pid variable's value before the program runs?

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

useconds_t BEAUTY_SLEEP = 500;

int main() {
    int        remains = 0;
    char       whoami[50];
    pid_t      pid;
    pid_t      ppid;

    printf("%d\n", pid); //debug
    printf("%d\n", getppid()); //debug
    fflush(stdout); //debug


    while (1) {

        if ((ppid = getppid()) == 2704 && (pid == 0)) {
            pid = fork();
            if (pid == -1) {
                perror("fork()");
                exit(1);
            }
            printf("%ld\n", (long)ppid);
            puts("beep");
        } else {
            usleep(BEAUTY_SLEEP);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I comment out "pid = fork()" in the while loop above, printf("%d\n", pid) prints the proper default value, 0.  However, when I restore the pid = fork() line, the print statement outputs a non-zero process ID.  Any clue as to why the retroactive assignment is happening?

Comment: Well, `pid` is undefined before the call.  After the call, it may or may not be zero, depending on whether it's the parent or child process.  Why don't you try *assigning* to it before attempting to access it?  Local variables do not default to zero, so this is undefined behavior.

Comment: There's no proper default for `pid`. Leaving an automatic variable uninitialized and then using it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. is there a way to check whether the variable has been assigned to a value? would pid == NULL work?

Comment: @TomKarzes the question is about `printf` tht comes *before* `fork`.

Comment: No, there is no way to check.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, I know.  And I'm telling you *anything* can change it.  The call requires arguments, spilled variables, etc.  Any of that could affect the stack size.  And that, in turn, could affect the random garbage it's printing out.  That's the nature of *undefined behavior*.  Seemingly unrelated changes can have an effect.  And that's why we don't even try to analyze the problem until the undefined behavior has been eliminated.